# check validation in loop while removing from array in angular 6 (template driven form)

Tags: angular, validation, ngfor

-- I have created random array with and without values.

-- without filling the details, remove the item from middle and last,

-- and fill the details add new button will be disabled still even details is filled.

So my concern is that how to handle validation even data is filled properly?

code below:

> **ts part:**

```
listArray = [
    {name: "dono", roll:2}, 
    {name:"", roll: 3},
    {name:"xyz", roll:4},
    {name:"", roll:9},
    {name:"abc", roll:null},
    ];

    remove(ind){
      this.listArray.splice(ind,1);
    }
    add(){
      this.listArray.push({name: "", roll: null});
    }
```

> **html part**

```
<form #validation="ngForm">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sno</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Roll</th>
    <th><button [disabled]="!validation.form.valid"  (click)="add()">Add New</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of listArray; let i= index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td><input required style="width:70px" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="na{{i}}"></td>
    <td><input required style="width:20px" [(ngModel)]="data.roll" name="roll{{i}}"></td>
    <td><button   (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

here is the link : [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-apcezi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

if any queries or don't understand the question comment below. thankyou for your time and response.

Comment: Could you please improve the question? Just checked your example - After filling all details in `form` the `Add new` button will be `enabled` and after this tried to remove and its still` enabled`. So did not understood your question.

Comment: from that example. without filling details,  please remove from middle and last and continue to remove and fill details. button will not enabled. did u get it ?